# Issues with retrieving image files in ionic/ angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-services

I am pretty new to ionic. I have a services file in my code where I have

```
.constant("myConfig", {
    "Area": "This Area",
    "1Url": "https://example.com/api/GetAppStructure?level=0&Area=",
    "2Url": "https://example.com/api/GetArea?MainGroup=",
    "1Icons": [{
        "Title": "Areawise",
        "Icon": "../img/area.png",
        "Src": "data:image/png;base64,iVNCsVP4oeiCkFgY6Baprnf0DcDqe4qsJ4BG4Pk4BYqBTKNzp+E7VfkPwcIjC8hjtafU/clqdgsZAp9C5J9B9ClbtpKZONf45T3SjMDHQSRhW7aQYVuMkFAOdpOCutXeq9kWhgyEaXw0/VeM1sUOhuGOgk3TcDvkPwCl5klNnSv0RO9VJJgx0khrDnSTBECfp..... "Alt": "area.png"
}
    ]
  })
```

Currently, The src parameter retrieves area as a base64 encoded image, but I want to access it via "../img/area.png" instead of the long base64 encoded string. However, it is not somehow not recognizing my img folder and hence the image listed. I tried removing ../ and just adding img/area.png still no luck. Is there any other way i can retrieve the image through the folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Use "Images" instead of "img" or "image".

Detail: In ionic we work inside "src" directory but when compiled, the ionic engine constructs cordova ready project inside "www" directory and the app actually runs here when running. Sometimes, the cordova asset directories do not match to the ones used in "src/assets" (due to capital letters etc.) and in-order to fix this, one can peek at the cordova directories inside "www/assets".
In my case, i was wrongly using "images" instead of "Images" and i believe that this same issue might be happening on your side.

Update: Put "assets/" at the start of your src url. Example: *"assets/Images/Timeline/icons/Negativo.png"*

Comment: try "assets/" at the start of your src url

Comment: tried assets/www/Images/image.png doesnt work either.Any other way I can replace that base 64 image?

Comment: Did you try one without www? Like "assets/Images/image.png".

Comment: yup, that doesnt work either. It shows a broken image icon